# I need a help in django

Tags: python, django

*whenever I try to add field in admin panel, I always get confused [][1]*
**model.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.base import ModelState

# Create your models here.
class Course(models.Model):
    faculty = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Semester(models.Model):
    sem = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    faculty = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    

class Subject(models.Model):
    faculty = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sem = models.ForeignKey(Semester, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subject_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

*which field is what? so I want every field is in clear name in admin panel*
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKXNO.png

Answer (score 2):

You have to add the built in `__str__` method into your model class like so:

```
class Semester(models.Model):
    sem = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    faculty = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.sem
```

That way Django knows what to print as a string for the model instance it is representing in the admin panel.

You can use a `F expression` to make it more dynamic:

```
class Semester(models.Model):
    sem = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    faculty = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Semester {self.sem} at Faculty {self.faculty}'
```

Comment: Thanks Bro I love you! and Iam following you! Appreciate that thanks @jonas

Comment: @UjjwolNeupane happy to. Consider accepting answers that solved your problem.